# Getting SSL Error when trying to download files from firebase storage - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

I've uploaded video file to firebase manually. Now I want to download this video from my ios app. I've also added below code inside info.plist file.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
  <dict>
   <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
   <true/>
 </dict>
```

At first for few requests it is possible to download files properly from app. But now I'm getting error:

> An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

I've checked that download Url link is opened from Chrome but is not opened from Safari.

Here my Xcode console shows NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com....

Thus I've also added below code inside my info.plist file

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>firebasestorage.googleapis.com</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionAllowInsecureHTTPSLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
        <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

But I've still got error

> An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the server cannot be made

Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For passing 2 frustrating days and giving a lot of time for R&D, Finally I've got this [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/4569) . "**This might be caused by networking conditions in some particular territories, rather than Google's firebase infrastructure.**"

I've tested my app using VPN and now all the files are downloaded from firebase storage perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem on a native android application. I was trying to upload "images" on the FirebaseStorage and i was getting this error.

```
Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error 

error:100000f7:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER.
```

After using a VPN everything is getting uploaded correctly. It was fine 5 days ago. What does that mean?

Comment: The error was fixed by itself after 3 days of pure waste of time